# Select all options in multiple select before submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've created a widget with two html multiple selects - "available" and "selected". User choose items from "available" and they are displayed in "selected", pretty simple stuff. I'monly interested in "selected" values (the other one simply doesn't have a name attribute) but for it to send all values they have to be selected.

I tried to select them all in jQuery "submit" event but for some reason it doesn't work. I can see they are all visualy selected before the form is sent but the data itself is not sent.

```
        var form = this.$selectedSelect[0].form;
        $(form).on('submit', function(e) {
            this.$selectedSelect.find("option").prop("selected", true);
        }.bind(this));
```

I'd like to avoid creating hidden fields for each "selected" entry.

Answer (score 2):

You should prevent the original submit process and invoke a new one after selecting all items like this:

```
var form = this.$selectedSelect[0].form;
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.$selectedSelect.find("option").prop("selected", true);
        this.submit();
    });
```

### UPDATE:

You don't even need to prevent the default vehaviour, the following sinmple solution is already sufficient:

```
 var form = this.$selectedSelect[0].form;
 $(form).submit(function(e) {
    this.$selectedSelect.find("option").prop("selected", true);
 });
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work (even with preventdefault), like i said i can see the elements being selected visualy but only the selection that was originaly there (before selecting all through code) is sent

Comment: @kasztelan have you tried using `.attr()` instead od `.prop()`?

Comment: @kasztelan I built a working fiddle using my code: http://jsfiddle.net/xqnhyxhz/ 
You need to give as some more code to allow any further help...

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").on("submit",function(eve){
            eve.preventDefault();
            $("select#someSelectId").find("option").prop("selected", true);
            $(this).submit();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: please see my comment to the other answer